# Need the equivalent of screen.width and screen.height on vb for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In VB6 I had the following code to dock a window:

```
Public Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    If IsBeingDragged = True And Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        'if the drag flag is true and left mouse button is pressed...

        'set Left side  docking
        If Me.Left + (x - Xs) < DockScale Then
            Me.Left = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'set Top side docking
        If Me.Top + (y - Ys) < DockScale Then
            Me.Top = 0
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'set right side docking
        If Me.Left + (x - Xs) + Me.Width > (Screen.Width - DockScale) Then
            Me.Left = Screen.Width - Me.Width
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'set bottom side docking
        If Me.Top + (y - Ys) + Me.Height > (Screen.Height - DockScale) Then
            Me.Top = Screen.Height - Me.Height
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'move the form finally
        Me.Left = Me.Left + (x - Xs)
        Me.Top = Me.Top + (y - Ys)
    End If
End Sub
```

I am using vb.net now and when I tried to copy and paste my code is telling me that screen.widht and screen.height are not members of the systems.window.form.screen, is there an equivalent to this on vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code to access the screen dimensions in VB.NET :

```
Dim curScreen As Screen
curScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen 'curScreen = Screen.AllScreens(0)
Dim height As Integer = curScreen.Bounds.Height
height = curScreen.WorkingArea.Height
```

You have to choose the screen you want and then decide what "framework" you want to deal with: `Bounds` (whole screen) or `WorkingArea` (whole screen without including the taskbar).